# Windows 7 64 bit, dual monitor issue

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

When I switch on the Windows logo (the square) appears on screen 2 (preceeded by the normal system startup files). However it then switches to screen 1 for the welcome, login screen. Its just annoying that everything does not start on screen 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Annoying, maybe... but necessary.  You're actually lucky enough to have a card configured to mirror by default.  In most cases, prior to loading the driver for the video-card, every port except for 1 is disabled completely.  After the driver is loaded, each display is initialized and made ready to use.

In all honesty, what would you want displayed on the other monitor prior to logging into your machine?

Comment: it used to be that everything started on a single screen and the second screen only fired up after I logged into windows

Comment: Did you update your drivers?

Comment: to be honest it only started happening after i stuck in a new quad core, would putting the screen connections onto the graphics card the other way around cause this?

Comment: Anything is possible.  I've seen many varieties of *default* configurations change simply because I had a monitor plugged into one port and added the 2nd to the other... and vise-versa.